# Total number of reviews different from the stats page

Tags: bug, review-queues, activity-tab

I noticed a discrepancy between the number of reviews I did as shown in the activity tab on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202253/etienne?tab=activity) (2129 at the time, see screenshot below) and the numbers shown for each review queue in the Stats (link like https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

[image]

Currently, I got:

- 47 in [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)
- 4 in [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats)
- 1037 in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats)
- 15 in [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats)
- 690 in [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)
- 61 in [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats)
- 611 in [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)
- 840 in [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats)

meaning I did 3305 reviews, and not 2129.

How is that possible?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: ... and deleted posts ...